# How can i check my CPU cache in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, cpu, cpu-cache, cpu-speed

i have a problem: i can not find any panel or command in windows 8 which can show me my CPU cache?

there is some softwares can get sysconfig. but those are not full info.
it's completely all information except CPU_CACHE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WMI to query the Cache. Here is a small C# program:

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WMISample
{
    public class MyWMIQuery
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", 
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor"); 

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Win32_Processor instance");
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("L2CacheSize: {0}", queryObj["L2CacheSize"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("L3CacheSize: {0}", queryObj["L3CacheSize"]);
                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was useful.but i want it in windows defult...not in programming method